# Non repeating random number generation with x(i+1) = x(i) + increment mod m

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, random

I have to generate millions of non-repeating random numbers and came across this equation:
$x_{i+1} = x_i+c \space(mod \ m)$, where c and m are relative primes and $m \geq total\ to\ be\ generated$.

This works ok since I don't need good random numbers and don't have to memorize them.
My question is, what is the demonstration and name of this method? 
I will have to write about it, but can't find any information not knowing how to formulate my question.

Comment: this is a number generator but not a random number generator

Comment: If this works for your needs, fine. However, if it is known that you use a linear congruential generator, any math major in the room can easily predict the next "random" number after they have seen a couple. For starters in cracking this, see the recent discussion on this site http://math.stackexchange.com/q/43948/11619

Comment: I added the *random* tag. Just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is called a "linear congruential generator".

Please have also a look at this question:

[how to generate real random numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40736/how-to-generate-real-random-numbers-with-some-random-and-pseudo-random/40790#40790)

The linear congruential generators are commonly considered to be a bad choice, with much better algorithms available, but it will depend on your application which generator turns out to  be good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator